# Functions with generics used as parameters in other functions

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Let's say I define a type `CoolType` like this:

```
type CoolType<T> = {message: string, result: T}
```

Then I define a `CoolFunction` type to describe a function that returns `CoolType`:

```
type CoolFunction = <T>() => CoolType<T>
```

`CoolFunction` is the type of parameter that a second function expects:

```
function superCoolFunction(coolFunction: CoolFunction) {
    return coolFunction()
}
```

Eventually, after all these definitions, I try to run some code like this:

```
const res = superCoolFunction(<string>() => {
    return {message: 'I am the message', result: 'I am the result'}
})
```

but, on `<string>() => {` of the above code I get an error from the compiler telling me that

> 'string' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133) Argument of
>   type '() => { message: string; result: string; }' is not
>   assignable to parameter of type 'CoolFunction'.   Call signature
>   return types '{ message: string; result: string; }' and 'CoolType'
>   are incompatible.
>       The types of 'result' are incompatible between these types.
>         Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'.
>           'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint
>   '{}'.ts(2345)

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Here's a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-pdkgau) that reproduces the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have generics in the wrong places. I think what you want is:

```
type CoolFunction<T> = () => CoolType<T>;
```

i.e. `CoolFunction`s also take a generic type. Then your higher-order function can propagate the generic:

```
function superCoolFunction<T>(coolFunction: CoolFunction<T>): CoolType<T> {
    return coolFunction();
}
```

Now the specific type can be inferred by the compiler:

```
superCoolFunction(() => ({ message: 'foo', result: 123 }));
// function superCoolFunction<number>(coolFunction: CoolFunction<number>): CoolType<number>
```

or supplied explicitly:

```
superCoolFunction<string>(() => ({ message: 'foo', result: 'bar' }));
```